AOSP Android tv build x86_64
I am trying to build a TV rom using aosp tv os. The build is done using m -j8 and I have setup and sourced acloud. Although when I try to launch the os it doesn't boot up. Even when I use launch_cvd it stuck at the android booting part and just the android logo keeps showing up. All the  files  seem to be correct. It's android 12

Please check whether system_server crashing or not in "adb logcat -b crash"
